# File path in C++ is incorrect in IIS w3wp process

Tags: c++, iis, io, iis-7.5

We created a DLL in C++ and used it in IIS process. This DLL should create a file in a path that we determined it directly in the code. When we run the application, IIS creates the file but not the given path, it is created where the IIS process is running `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv`

we wrote this code in C++ :

```
FILE* fpLastMsgID = _fsopen(m_csFileName, "r", _SH_DENYNO);
if(fpLastMsgID != NULL)
{
...
}
```

This DLL works properly when we use it in a console application.
How can we specify the file path in C++ for IIS to create our file?

Comment: Make `m_csFileName` contain the absolute path to the file?

Comment: yes it contains the absolute path